# Binary Search Tree with 2 keys

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I have a database of users with their usernames and id's. These are the operations that program will process:

`insert`, `delete` (by `username`), `search` (by `username`), `print` (prints all users info, sorted by their `id`)

time complexity of first 3 operations shouldn't be more than `O(log n)` and for print it should be `O(n)`. solution should be implemented with a balanced BST.

My idea to solve the problem is to have to 2 BST, key of one is `id` and for another is `username`. So we can access an element by their name or id both in O(log n) time. But this doubles memory space and time of operations.

Is there a way to access elements both by their `username` and `id` in `O(log n)` time in a better way than what i explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My idea to solve the problem is to have to 2 BST, key of one is `id` and
>   for another is `username`. So we can access an element by their `username` or
>   `id` both in `O(log n)` time. But this doubles memory space and time of
>   operations.

What you propose will indeed double the memory and time requirements for your data structure. (Only insertions and deletions will take double time. The other operations will take no extra time). However, recall that `O(2 log n)` is generally treated the same as `O(log n)` and is much less than `O(n)`. As an illustration, I've graphed `2 log n` and `n`. Note that they are equal when `n` is `2` or `4`. `log n` is essentially a flat line compared to `n`.
[image]

I propose that you cannot do better than this using balanced BSTs (or at all, for that matter). Since you need to search based on `username` in `O(log n)` time, `username` must be the key for the tree. However, you also need to retrieve the users sorted by `id` in `O(n)` time. That essentially forbids you from sorting them after retrieving them, because you won't be able to sort them faster than `O(n log n)`. Thus, they must already be sorted by `id`. Therefore, `id` must be a key for the tree. Hence, you need two trees.

Answer (score 2):

While 2 trees are fine, you can also use a hash table for lookup and delete plus a sorted index for printing. A red-black tree will be fine for the sorted index.

***However***, if IDs are consecutive non-negative integers, it will be even more efficient to maintain a simple array, where position `i` contains the object with the ID of `i`.  Now you can print by just traversing the array.  And the hash table values can be IDs, for these "point" to the respective object in the array.

Comment: Using a simple array fails when you need to delete a user, because the resulting shift operation is `O(n) > O(log n)`

Comment: Not true if you do it correctly. Don't shift the array. Chain the slots corresponding deleted entries in a free list and reuse them (along with associated IDs) for new inserts. This was a very common technique when memory was more expensive than it is now.  The space needed for my scheme can easily be 4 times less than for two separate red-black trees due to overhead for nodes, flags, 8-byte pointers (instead of 4-byte array indices), etc.

Comment: If you can guarantee this will be the case and remember to skip over deleted entries that haven't been filled back up yet, then this could indeed be a very good solution...

Comment: Yes the main disadvantage is that printing will be O(n) where n is the largest size the database has ever been. But even if 3/4 or more of the entries are deleted, traversing a contiguous array is likely to be faster than traversing a tree.